# NullPointerException on Hibernate new Configuration();

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, nullpointerexception, hibernate-mapping

This is my first time trying out Hibernate with Eclipse and the following are the things I did:

1. Created a Java Bean called Student.java which is as follows:

   ```
   package com.jwt.hibernate;

   public class Student {

   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String degree;
   private String roll;
   private String phone;

   public long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getDegree() {
       return degree;
   }
   public void setDegree(String degree) {
       this.degree = degree;
   }
   public String getRoll() {
       return roll;
   }
   public void setRoll(String roll) {
       this.roll = roll;
   }
   public String getPhone() {
       return phone;
   }
   public void setPhone(String phone) {
       this.phone = phone;
   }   

   }
   ```
2. Created a mapping file, **Student.hbm.xml** as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.jwt.hibernate.Student" table="student">

<id column="ID" name="id" type="long" />
<property column="name" name="name" type="string" />
<property column="degree" name="degree" type="string" />
<property column="roll" name="roll" type="string" />
<property column="phone" name="phone" type="string" />

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

3. Created the hibernate configuration file, **hibernate.cfg.xml** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatetutorial</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create </property>

<mapping resource="com/jwt/hibernate/Student.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

4. Created the class **SimpleTest.java** which is as follows:

   ```
   package com.jwt.hibernate;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    public class SimpleTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
       cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

       SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
       Session session = factory.openSession();

       Student student = new Student();
       student.setName("Mukesh");
       student.setRoll("101");
       student.setPhone("8888");
       student.setDegree("B.E");

       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
       session.save(student);
       System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
       tx.commit();

       session.close();
       factory.close();
   }

   }
   ```

Now, when I try to run SimpleTest, I get the following error:

```
**INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:295)
    at com.jwt.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:221)
    ... 4 more**
```

I double checked and made sure that all the configuration and jar files were added to the classpath. So that is not the problem. I would really appreciate some insights as to what may have caused this problem and inturn, how to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing much that you could have done wrong here, as it's failing on the first line of code. All I can think of is a conflict in versions of the Hibernate libraries/dependencies. How are you building / what are you including on the class path? Perhaps post your `pom.xml` if you use maven, or similar.

Comment: I'm including the MySQL driver and the jar's for hibernate in the build path. Also, I'm using hibernate-release-4.3.7.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend updating to later version of SLF4J.
Or
Your `Hibernate.cfg.xml` is not on classpath. What folder is it in?

Edit :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
```

This is actual exception in your code, If your `Hibernate.cfg.xml` is loaded then check for `SELF4J` version, Don't use `user library` to take your jar files, put all libraries in your lib folder and then configure those in class path.

Comment: again, config cannot be the problem as the config is not yet loaded at the moment of the abort.

Answer (score 0):

You may find a Java Configuration of Hibernate to be more friendly. Here is an example of one that I did (Note: there are Spring annotations like @Autowired and @PostConstruct in this class so don't get confused):

```
public class HibernateConfigBean {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateConfigBean.class);

    @Autowired private Environment environment;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Configuration configuration;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", environment.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", environment.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", environment.getProperty("db_username"));
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", environment.getProperty("db_password"));

        //Add additional Annotated Classes here
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UserEntity.class);

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    //This should be visible outside of the package as it's only used by the GenerateDbSchema class
    void generateSchema() throws Exception {
        try{
            new SchemaExport(configuration).create(false, true);
        } catch (RuntimeException re){
            throw new Exception(re);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just put my values into a properties file :-)

Comment: while this is certainly "nicer" nowadays than XML configuration, it cannot be the cause of OP's problem. The exception happens on the first line, even before the config is being loaded.